Using Feeds to create a content item from XML, then Rules to Publish
One of our sites has Feeds set up to download XML files and create News and Event content types that were created on other Drupal sites. The new items are automatically published after the feed importer is run by cron.
On another site, we copied this configuration, but also set up a Workflow with the states Draft, Unpublished and Published. New content created by users/editors (including News and Events content types) is assigned Draft state unless they change it.
When the Feeds are run on the site with the Workflow set up, the newly imported items are Unpublished state.  I tried mapping a default value of 1 to the Published (status) target but that had no effect.
I also set up mapping a log message of feed-item to the Revision log message (revision_log) target, then trying to set of a Rule with a condition to look for the log message then publish the content. Not having luck figuring this part out.
The Owner in the Feeds processor setting is the admin which has full permissions.
Any ideas?

Did you debug this with Xdebug?  You first need to determine if Feeds is not applying the value for Published, or if the code for "New content created by users/editors (including News and Events content types) is assigned Draft state unless they change it." is undoing the published status after Feeds does its processing. Entities created by Feeds will generally call all the hooks and emit all the events that entities created in the UI do, so you will have to add something to get Feeds entities to be treated differently from UI entities.

It's a little confusing to me what you're trying to do - do you want to automatically publish imported entities, or do you want editor review first? If you want to use Rules you can create a Rule to publish these entities. Trigger the Rule on both "After updating a news entity" and "After updating a event entity". The Condition will be "Data comparision" and you will check that the "original" status was "draft" and the new status is "unpublished". That indicates a change was made to the status. The Rule can then use an action to "Set data value" and change the status to published.
